# Soldermask impact to guard-ring circuit

Tags: solder-mask

Guard-ring circuit is designed aroung high sensitive (low current high impedance inputs). What is the technical impact if a guard-ring circutry is fully masked versus unmask ?

Comment: A guard ring is normally used to prevent leakage currents through surface contamination of the PCB. If the ring is isolated from the contamination by soldermask, it can't do its job.

Comment: @DaveTweed You should make that an answer.

Comment: @DaveTweed Reference [here](http://www.linear.com/solutions/1853) from LTC says the same thing.

Answer (score 9):

A guard ring is normally used to stop leakage currents that flow through surface contamination of the PCB, by shunting them to a low-impedance node. If the ring is isolated from the contamination by soldermask, it can't do its job.

Answer (score 3):

The solder masks generally used to reduce moisture infiltration to the PCB (thus can prevent leakage in some degree), but there may be surface-charge problems when using large area solder-mask. So the better approach is to use bare-copper guard area around sensitive nodes. Using solder or plating the guard with gold or tin to prevent oxidation. The guard trace is to provide a path for the leakage to the low impedance node, so they should not be covered by solder mask.

And There are some similar discuss: http://www.eevblog.com/forum/reviews/6632a-teardown/

> ... you can clearly see the guard traces ( silver ) . the reason for
>   removing the soldermask over the guard is to remove that pathway as
>   well. Soldermask has a specific dielectric constant that is worse than
>   air. By removing the soldermask you make a lower leakage capacitance
>   across the guard ring.
>
> Notice on the left bottom pin that there is again a guard ring
>   present. For some reason they forgot to open the soldermask (  i
>   looked carefully and it is a guard ring ... )

Comment: Are you confusing soldermask with conformal coating? Normally, soldermask has so many openings through it that it can't have any significant effect on moisture.

Comment: Yes, in a big board, there may be many openings. But if we want to protect a small area, we can indeed cover it with a mask.

Comment: It doesn't matter how big the board is, there are at least two openings for each component on it.

Comment: @DaveTweed: Yes there many openings, and they have limited effect on moisture. But **limited** or **insignificant** not equal to no-use or nothing :).